# Using SignalR Client in UWP running on Windows IoT

Tags: serial, sensor, windows-iot

I'm running Windows IoT on a Raspberry Pi.

After I turn on my Raspberry Pi and Windows IoT starts up, I want to automatically begin reading sensor data from a serial port continuously, and also send the data to a SignalR server/hub continuously. I don't need any UI.

I'm new at UWP apps. I want to use a SignalR client to send the data near real-time.

Questions:

1. Is it possible to use SignalR on Windows IoT? And if yes, how would I do that?
2. Is there any best practice to read send sensor data and send them to
       a SignalR Hub in near real time? How can I read and send data continuously?

I just want to run these steps:

1. Start Raspberry Pi
2. Start automatically app
3. Start automatically infinite loop

   - read sensor data
   - send sensor data to a SignalR Hub

I don't know if there is any better way instead of using an infinite loop to read an send data continously.

Comment: So what's the question? How to reduce lag or how to run singnalr?

Comment: Thank you and welcome to Raspberry Pi Exchange. It seems like the dominant question is if you can actually run SignalR on IoT on the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/deployment/tutorial-signalr-self-host  - You can try and deploy it this way. But not 100% sure if it will work...

Comment: @ppumkin Yes and also how can I read and send data continuously. I edited my question again. :)

Comment: @ppumkin I also thought about trying signalr.selfhost.

Comment: To read data continuously you need to opena socket to the signalR server. If the Pi is meant to be the server then the clients need to be able to create scokets by either using the SignalR DLL or AJAX or HTML Sockets. But I dont think IoT will be able to run SignalR. You can run it on Debian with Mono, that will work fine.

Comment: @ppumkin The Pi should be a signalR client. And with continuously I meant, that once the Pi is started, reading and sending data should start automatically and only ends when Pi is shut down.

Comment: OK.. I think client is allot easier. I saw several examples while crawling around the Internet. Please have a quick search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SignalR **client** is basically installed into your Universal App by running the following package install commands (or using the NuGet GUI)

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client
Install-Package PropertyChanged.Fody
```

There is an excellent post here with step by step.

http://blog.chrisbriggsy.com/SignalR-Win10-IoT/

I do not think it is easy to get the server side of SignalR to run on Windows IoT yet. It is possible to get the server going with Xamarin Mono on Debian with NoWin HTTP Server. The issue is that SignalR requires to run a dedicated HTTP server and that is not possible on the Core version because of sandboxing... (but maybe that will change or there seem to be some hacks floating about)